# Configuring a filter for Fail2ban and Bookstack

Tags: regex, bash, fail2ban

I cannot successfully configure fail2ban filter for working with Bookstack.
I tried 3 differents regex checker, they're all catching the log lines, but when i try with failban-regex tool, it don't hit anything.

Apache error logs file:

```
[Mon Sep 11 10:41:55.375879 2023] [php:notice] [pid 30757] [client 82.32.100.175:52892] Failed login for admin@admin.com, referer: https://bookstack.exemple.com/login
[Mon Sep 11 10:44:55.883100 2023] [php:notice] [pid 30743] [client 100.154.118.1:59728] Failed login for Admin@admin.com, referer: https://bookstack.exemple.com/login
```

fail2ban/filter.d/bookstack.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex = (\[client <HOST>\]) (Failed login for .*?[^,]+)
```

jail.local:

```
[bookstack]
 enabled = true
 port = http,https
 logpath = %(apache_error_log)s
 filter = bookstack
```

$ sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/bookstack.conf --print-all-matched >

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : bookstack, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/error.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [51] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 51 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 51 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 51 lines
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks you very much for your time.

Comment: What OS do you use? Is there a firewall configured?

Comment: Ubuntu server 22.04. Sudo ufw status : Status: inactive

Comment: I had a similar problem. It might not be a problem with failtoban, but with the firewall. Try to activate UFW. Do you run on a VPS?

Comment: I do use an vps (AWS EC2). I just configured and  enable ufw, but unfortunatly it don't change anything for fail2ban.

Comment: Looks like your situation is different from mine, but you can check that `netfilter-persistent` is running, i.e. `service --status-all`. In my case this service was not running.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help John. I appreciate. I just added netfilter-persistent and enabled it. But Fail2ban still don't catch my logs. I suspect my regex is good, fail2ban also but probably a parameter is misconfigured.
I tried to modify my bookstack.conf as follow (found on github):
`datepattern = {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %%k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
failregex = .*client <HOST>.*Failed login from .*?`

But it still don't work

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the issue. However, I'm not sure how.
Might be because of UFW or netfilter-persistent. I will soon try to re-install the server to test the two possibilities.

Here is the bookstack.conf:

```
datepattern = {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %%k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
failregex = .*client <HOST>.*Failed login for .*?
```

This regex also works fine (without datepattern):

```
failregex = ^.*\[client <HOST>:\d+\] Failed login for.*?[^,]+
```

In the end, I have added some more settings in my jail.local (it was previously missing):

```
maxretry = 3
bantime = 300
```

EDIT: In case it can be useful for someone else. I re-installed the server, and it working WITHOUT **netfilers-persistent** neither **UFW**.